# How can I connect successfully to my Oracle Database using SQLPlus

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

I keep trying to open a connection between my computer and my Oracle database using SQLPlus.

I'm using the command:

```
sqlplus USERNAME@server.domain.com:4075/DBNAME.WORLD
```

And it keeps returning:

```
TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

tnsnames.ora contains:

```
DBNAME.WORLD =
 (DESCRIPTION =
   (ADDRESS_LIST =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = server.domain.com))(PORT = 4075))
   )
(CONNECT_DATA =
  (SID = DBNAME)
  (SRVR = DEDICATED)
 )
)
```

And I'm using a sqlnet file provided by my employer:

```
AUTOMATIC_IPC = OFF
TRACE_LEVEL_SERVER = OFF
TRACE_LEVEL_CLIENT = OFF
SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME = 0
NAMES.DEFAULT_DOMAIN = world
NAME.DEFAULT_ZONE = world
SQLNET.CRYPTO_SEED = "ENCRYPTIONSEED"
SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_CLIENT = REJECTED
SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_TYPES_CLIENT = (DES40)
SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_SERVER = REJECTED
SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_TYPES_SERVER = (DES40)
SQLNET.CRYPTO_CHECKSUM_CLIENT = REJECTED
SQLNET.CRYPTO_CHECKSUM_TYPES_CLIENT = (MD5)
SQLNET.CRYPTO_CHECKSUM_SERVER = REJECTED
SQLNET.CRYPTO_CHECKSUM_TYPES_SERVER = (MD5)
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH = (TNSNAMES)
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (BEQ,NONE)
```

How can I troubleshoot this "could not resolve the connect identifier" error and open a connection to my oracle database?

Comment: sqplus username/password@dbname.word  sqlplus -help shows you the options.

Comment: This is still returning "TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the entry in your tnsnames.ora file, you don't have to mention the server name and port again.

This would be sufficient -

```
sqlplus USERNAME@DBNAME.WORLD
```

(if you want it to prompt for password)

Or you could do as OldProgrammer says in the comment if it is okay to have password in plain text.

Comment: This is still returning "TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified."

Comment: Are you in windows or linux? And does the environment variable ORACLE_HOME point to the correct location?

Comment: I'm in Linux. Yes, ORACLE_HOME points to /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_1

Comment: Does `sqlplus username@server.domain.com:4075` work?

Comment: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Answer (score 0):

While other are correct about how you should be connecting:

```
sqlplus USERNAME@DBNAME.WORLD
```

optionally with the password on the command line too, you also have a problem in your `tnsnames.ora` file, which will cause you to still get `ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified`.

Your `connect_data` line is not indented, [which is invalidating the whole file](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10835/syntax.htm#NETRF172). Indentation helps understanding of the file anyway, but is crucial here:

> Any keyword in a configuration file that begins a parameter that includes one or more keyword-value pairs must be in the far left column of a line. If it is indented by one or more spaces, then it is interpreted as a continuation of the previous line.

So make sure the lines related to an alias are all indented below it, with only the alias name starting right at the start of a line.

You also have an extra closing parenthesis, after your host key/value pair, which will also cause that error even if the file is indented correctly.

```
DBNAME.WORLD =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = server.domain.com)(PORT = 4075))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = DBNAME)
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
    )
  )
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still seeing the error. The tnsnames file was actually indented properly, but got skewed when posting.

Comment: @KinsDotNet - you have an extra right parenthesis too; `(HOST = server.domain.com))` shoudl be `(HOST = server.domain.com)`.

Comment: Still getting the error after fixing the parenthesis. I'm starting to wonder if this might be a firewall issue.

Comment: @KinsDotNet - it isn't a firewall issues, it isn't gettingthat far; it's a problem with the TNS alias you're using, the tnsnames.ora file, or your session's ability to see the file. Is anything else in the file? Where is it located, and do you have a TNS_ADMIN environment variable set?

Comment: No TNS_ADMIN variable is set, do I set it to the path of the tnsnames file?. Nothing else is in the tnsnames file except the one definition.

Comment: If it isn't in the default location then yes, set it to the directory the file is in. And export it.

Comment: Same problem. The file was in the default location anyways.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73260/discussion-between-alex-poole-and-kinsdotnet).